# Problema saltos de linea Visual Studio Code

Tags: vscode

actualmente me encuentro con un problema en la configuración de Visual Studio.
No consigo encontrar la opción que elimina o me permite ajustar donde corta cada linea de código.
esto hace que mi código se autoajuste de forma automática, no permitiéndome darle el formato visual que me gustaría en muchos casos.
¿Hay forma de desactivar o mas bien ajustar este parámetro?

Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La configuración de esa barra implica por lo menos tres configuraciones distintas.

Abre la configuración del VSCode (archivo settings.json) y añade las siguientes líneas:

```yml
"editor.rulers": [80],
"editor.wordWrapColumn": 80,
"editor.wordWrap": "off"
```

- La primera establece el número de columna donde se mostrará la línea.
- La segunda hace que se cambie de línea automáticamente al llegar a ese número de columna.
- La tercera línea desactiva dicho salto de línea.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Solucionado!, además no tenia idea de estos tres parametros!